# How to render table columns dynamically using single ng-repeat for colgroup, thead and tbody

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have columns definitions `JSON` and I want to apply few properties on `<col>` in `<colgroup>`, few on `<th>` in `<thead><tr>` and few on `<td>` in `<tbody>` using single `ng-repeat`.

It is easily achievable by using multiple `ng-repeat` either on `<col>`, `<th>`, `<td>`  or their immediate parent elements. But I want to avoid multiple iterations.

**Table Template**

```
<!-- language: lang-markup -->
<table id={{metaData.id}} name="{{metaData.name}}" class="{{metaData.classes}}">
    <colgroup>
        <col ng-repeat="col in metaData.columns" class="{{col.classes}}" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th 
                ng-repeat="col in metaData.columns"
                class="{{col.classes}}"
                ng-class="{'vk-sortable': col.sortable, 'vk-editable' : col-editable"
                >{{col.title}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="col in metaData.columns"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="col in metaData.columns"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Columns JSON**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
{
"id": "tblCustomer",
"name": "tblCustomer",
"columns": [
    {
        "id" : "thCustIndex",
        "name" : "thCustIndex",
        "title" : "Sr. #",
        "classes" : "",
        "type" : "index",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id" : "thCustId",
        "name" : "thCustId",
        "title" : "Id",
        "classes" : "align-center",
        "type" : "text",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id" : "thCustName",
        "name" : "thCustName",
        "title" : "Name",
        "classes" : "",
        "type" : "text",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id" : "thCustDob",
        "name" : "thCustDob",
        "title" : "Date Of Birth",
        "classes" : "",
        "type" : "date",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id" : "thCustMobile1",
        "name" : "thCustMobile1",
        "title" : "Mobile 1",
        "classes" : "",
        "type" : "inMobile",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id" : "thCustEmail",
        "name" : "thCustEmail",
        "title" : "E-mail Id",
        "classes" : "align-center",
        "type" : "email",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    },
    {
        "id" : "thCustAddress",
        "name" : "thCustAddress",
        "title" : "Address",
        "classes" : "",
        "type" : "text",
        "sortable" : "true",
        "editable" : "false"
    }
]
```

}